# login and userID toolbar

Tags: c#, asp.net

I looking for a tutorial of how i can make my wesite toobar show the name of the user after he login so he can just press on his name in the toolbar and move him to his personal page such as your user name and your photo on the top of the forums.

Many thanks

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_

Comment: Hi Soner, i am still beginner and i am looking for some tutorial of how i can do what i asked for if u have any links where i can learn more of this topic i will be thanks for you.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in several different ways, however this is probably the simplest.  Save the username in a session variable:

```
Session["UserName"]  = txtUsername.text;
```

and in all the other pages , you will need to have a Label that shows the name of the user who is currently logged in. You can get the value from the "session" in this way:

```
labelUser.Text   = Session["UserName"].Tostring();
```

Do not forget to set the session to null when the user logs out:

```
Session["Username"] = null
```

How to redirect on his page, just use again the value of session variable to redirect to his page.